# Selenium is not clicking on the cookie accept button

Tags: python, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver, click

Im trying to click on the cookie accept button but selenium is not clicking on it. Can anybody help me?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get('https://www.bisnode.de/upik/')
try:
    buttonlink = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))
    )
    buttonlink.click()
    time.sleep(10)
except:
    driver.quit()
```

Edit:
Somebody mentioned Im using an ID which exists twice so I should look by another css selector. So I replaced the line but its still not working.

```
buttonlink = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))
        )
        buttonlink.click()
```

Its opening the chrome browser and the webpage but then it just quits. There is no error output.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 elements with `onetrust-accept-btn-handler` ID there, so you have to change your locator.
Try this `css_selector` `button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler`

Comment: How can I find in the feature by myself easily out in Chrome that there are two elements with the same ID?

And if im trying to replace my line with EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))
    )
    buttonlink.click()
its still not working :/

Comment: Just open the dev tools by pressing the F12. Then on Elements tab there do Ctrl+F to search elements on the DOM. Then search according to onetrust-accept-btn-handler. You will see count 2 and you will be able to go to each one of them with arrows appearing on the right to the search field

Comment: Try adding a short sleep between the `buttonlink = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "onetrust-accept-btn-handler"))` and the `buttonlink.click()`

Comment: Sometimes during the elements rendering element can be defined as clickable while it is still not really ready to accept clicks . That's why it's commonly better to use element is visible condition.

Answer (score 1):

I've spent 30 minutes on solving this issue.

The problem is that the button is not clickable until corresponding script is executed.
So, what is required here is to wait until the style of the parent div changes to
`bottom: 1rem'`

#### Solution:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


url = 'https://www.bisnode.de/upik/'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/snap/bin/chromium.chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[style='bottom: 1rem'] button[id*='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']")))
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[style='bottom: 1rem'] button[id*='onetrust-accept-btn-handler']").click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the CSS_SELECTOR:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 5).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "onetrust-banner-sdk")))

time.sleep(5)

acceptbutton = browser.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
acceptbutton.click()
```